# How to dynamically adjust the dimensions of a canvas based on the content inside a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, canvas

I'm using [PDF JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/) in a Vue3 project and I want to overlay a `<canvas id="draw_canvas">` on the rendered pdf document. Thus, allowing me to programmatically draw rectangles over the pdf document as an attempt to place a marker on certain places.

The way PDF JS renders a pdf file is by placing the content of each page inside individual `<canvas>` elements. I have 2 Vue SFCs called `App` and `Child`. The `Child` component loads and renders the pages of the pdf document (3 pages) inside a `<div id="pages_container">`. This `div` is enclosed inside another one, `<div id="doc_container">`, which is made scrollable.

To adjust the height of `<canvas id="draw_canvas">` whenever `<div id="pages_container">` grows, I'm using a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver). This observes the `<div id="pages_container">` for changes in size and then adjusts the height of the `<canvas id="draw_canvas">` to match its `offsetHeight`.

```
// Child.vue

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';

// function to load pdf file and render its pages
const loadDoc = () => {
   pdfjsLib.getDocument("doc.pdf").promise.then((pdfDoc) => {
      const pageCount = pdfDoc._pdfInfo.numPages;
      
      for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
         pdfDoc.getPage(i)
            .then((page) => {
               // get the viewport object of the page in the pdf
               const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.25, });

               // create a new canvas to place the content of this page
               const newPageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
               newPageCanvas.setAttribute("id", "page_" + i);
               newPageCanvas.setAttribute("class", "pdf-page-canvas");
               newPageCanvas.width = viewport.width;
               newPageCanvas.height = viewport.height;

               // add the page canvas to the DOM
               document.getElementById("pages_container").appendChild(newPageCanvas);

               // render page
               const renderContext = {
                  canvasContext: newPageCanvas.getContext("2d"),
                  viewport: viewport
               };
               page.render(renderContext);
            });
      }
   });
}

// function to place a marker on the pdf document
const placeBox = (x, y, width, height) => {
   console.log("Draw box with attributes: ", x, y, width, height);

   const drawCanvasContext = document.querySelector("#draw_canvas").getContext("2d");
   drawCanvasContext.strokeStyle = "red";
   drawCanvasContext.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
}

defineExpose({placeBox,});

onMounted(() => {
   loadDoc();

   const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
      console.log("Height changed!");

      const drawCanvas = document.querySelector("#draw_canvas");
      const offsetHeight = document.querySelector("#pages_container").offsetHeight;
      
      console.log(`Div offset height: ${offsetHeight}`);
      console.log(`Canvas old height: ${drawCanvas.height}`);

      drawCanvas.height = offsetHeight;

      console.log(`canvas new height: ${drawCanvas.height}`);
   });

   observer.observe(document.querySelector("#pages_container"));
});
</script>


<template>
   <div id="doc_container">
      <div id="pages_container">
         <!-- the canvases that contain the pdf pages will be placed in here -->
      </div>
      <canvas id="draw_canvas"></canvas>
   </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
#doc_container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   border: 1px solid green;
}

#pages_container {
   border: 2px dashed red;
}

#draw_canvas {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: gray;
   opacity: 0.6;
}
</style>
```

By printing out the `offsetHeight` of `<div id="pages_container">` whenever changed, I noted the max height it grows to is 3171px. So, the max height `<canvas id="draw_canvas">` must also be 3171px, but it is not. It *appears* to be exceeding that value.

[image: screenshot]

I have given the `<div id="pages_container">` a dashed red border and the `<canvas id="drawCanvas">` a gray background colour with an opacity of 0.6. In the screenshot above, we can see that the canvas exceed the div in height. I don't understand why.

How do I adjust the height of this canvas so that it matches the height of `<div id="pages_container">` ?

The `Child` component is placed inside the `App` component. Here's the link to the document I used: [doc.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mEbBE2VQwt32QuUVT2DqXvVVVu73_UpZ/view?usp=sharing).

```
// App.vue

<script setup>
import Child from './components/Child.vue';

const childRef = ref(null);
</script>

<template>
   <div id="form_container">
      <!-- a form will be shown here to collect data to draw the box on the PDF document -->
   </div>

   <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
      <Child ref="childRef"/>
   </div>

</template>

<style scoped>
#form_container {
   float: left; 
   border: 2px solid blue; 
   width: 50%; 
   height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

Here's the `index.html` file with the CDNs to use PDF JS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Test PDF Project</title>
      <link href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/web/pdf_viewer.min.css " rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/build/pdf.min.js "></script>
      
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an example that reproduces your problem!

Comment: @imhvost I edited the question so that you can reproduce the problem

Comment: Don't add an "edit: ...", just work it into the post so it's one cohesive question that follows the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks! I made the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML `<canvas>` element actually has two dimensions, the intrinsic dimensions (using the .width and .height properties you're modifying in JS) and the displayed dimensions (controlled in CSS with their width & height properties)

In your case, you're modifying the intrinsic dimensions when you set `drawCanvas.height = offsetHeight;`, but this is then getting scaled because in CSS you're defining the CSS width as `100%`

Instead, try setting the style.height property to the offset height. You also need to manually specify that these are `px` measurements for the style properties, which you don't need to do for the intrinsic dimensions.

```js
drawCanvas.style.height = `${offsetHeight}px`;
```

If this gets you a lot closer but it's still not exactly the same, it's worth noting that the `offsetHeight` value includes the inner height, padding and border - whereas you are only setting the inner height of the canvas so any padding + borders it has will be added on top so it may still be a little larger unless you account for this.

[W3C spec on canvas dimensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/the-canvas-element.html#:%7E:text=The%20intrinsic%20dimensions%20of%20the,to%20fit%20this%20layout%20size.)